# Sync HTTP request (HttpURLConnection) with high concurrency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, push-notification

I am using `HttpURLConnection` in my Java (Spring) app to send HTTP requests to external third-party servers. I need about 1000 http requests per second.

However, IMHO `HttpURLConnection` is synchronous, thus *one thread* can only do *one* http request, and only after that request is finished, this thread can do the next request. Therefore, this seems to be non-efficient, and I suspect this cannot even be handled (please correct me if I am wrong, e.g. this is actually very efficient).

I wonder whether there is a good way to handle these? IMHO I will use a thread pool (Executor) containing, say, 100 threads.

P.S. I *cannot* use any other libraries such as `HttpClient` since that SDK package is provided by third party :/

Thanks very much!

Comment: Why is HttpClient off the table but HttpURLConnection still available? What about raw Sockets?

Comment: @Charlie Unfortunately, I am using 3rd party libs (e.g. XiaoMi Push), and I do not have their source code, only a jar file :( They choose HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

1.You are right about the request in one Thread.It is mentioned in the HttpURLConnection  document

```
* Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request
 * but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be
 * transparently shared by other instances. Calling the close() methods
 * on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection
 * after a request may free network resources associated with this
 * instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection.
 * Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket
 * if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.
 *
```

That means that you could use  openConnection to get a new HttpURLConnection instance,then do request and close that.The the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instance.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to do it efficiently :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Socket` and `SocketChannel`s might be a good option, although you'll have to 'roll your own' HTTP, which will be Very Not Easy if you have to deal with HTTPS. They are part of the standard JRE and can also be used asynchronously. You get into some hairy code when you go async because the `Selector` API is a bit difficult to work with but it would definitely be fast and have low overhead.

You might be able to use a custom SSLSocketFactory to jocky the socket so that you have direct access to the socket to get a SocketChannel from.

Comment: Sorry I *cannot* touch the code using HttpURLConnection, which is deep inside some 3rd party library :(